# Error: The pipe 'slice' could not be found

Tags: angular

I'm working on the frontend of a Web App with Angular. At the moment, I'm trying to include a sort of Excel page in it. So I tried to follow the template https://medium.com/query-ai/create-a-spreadsheet-with-angular-and-mat-table-part-1-33f6378a1f82. This is what I've done:

```
<div class="pageContiner">

    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef=" ">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let rIndex = index;">
  
              <a class="header-value"> {{header}} </a>
              <!--Input tag the only show up when editpointer col and row equal to the location of the cell-->
  
              <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteRow(rIndex)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button mat-icon-button (click)="addRow(rIndex)">
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
              </button>
            {{rIndex + 1}}
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container *ngFor="let header of displayedColumns | slice:1:displayedColumns.length; index as cindex" [cdkColumnDef]="header">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            
            <a class="header-value"> {{header}} </a>
            
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteColumn(cindex)">
              <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="addColumn(cindex)">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
  
          </mat-header-cell>
  
          <!-- when switch function is called then the value of editpointer and trucker will change accordingly
          ngClass will change the color of the background of the edited cell-->
          <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let element; index as rindex" (click)="switchToInput(rindex, cindex)"
          [ngClass]="{'activeCell': editor.editPointer.col === cindex && editor.editPointer.row === rindex}">
               <!-- input and ngIf direacter to switch between to editing mode 
               if editpointer col and row equal to cindex and rindex than switch to input-->
              <a  *ngIf="editor.editPointer.col != cindex || editor.editPointer.row != rindex" class="cell-value"> {{element[cindex]}} </a>
              <input matInput *ngIf="editor.editPointer.col === cindex && editor.editPointer.row === rindex" [(ngModel)]="element[cindex]" #value="ngModel" name="value">
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
  
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  
  </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/services/notification/notification.service';

export let SheetHeader = [
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        '],
  ['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ']
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timesheet',
  templateUrl: './timesheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timesheet.component.scss']
})
export class TimesheetComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(SheetHeader);
  editor = {
    //use to change the switch to input
    editPointer: {
      col: -1,
      row: -1,
    },
  };

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private notify: NotificationService) {}

  switchToInput(rindex, cindex) {
    this.editor.editPointer.col = cindex;
    this.editor.editPointer.row = rindex;
  }
  
  deleteColumn(cindex) {

    // keep the length of columns to loop the data with later
    const columnsLength = this.displayedColumns.length;

    // prevent deleting all headers (=columns).
    if ( this.displayedColumns.length === 1 ) {
      this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.CANNOT_DELETE_ALL_COLUMNS'));
      return;
    }
    
    //delete specific header
    this.displayedColumns.splice(cindex + 1, 1);

    // adjust header's names.
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.displayedColumns.length - 1; i++ ) {
      this.displayedColumns[i+1] = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    }

    let newRow = [];
    const newDataSource = [];
    // loop dataSource and copy every value exept the one in deleted column
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.data.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < columnsLength; j++) {
        if (j !== cindex) { //if doesn't equal the deleted header than copy
          newRow.push(this.dataSource.data[i][j]);
        }
      }
      newDataSource.push(newRow);
      newRow = [];
    }

    this.dataSource.data = newDataSource;
  }

  addColumn(cindex) {

    // add header to displayedColumn
    if ( cindex !== 0 ) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(cindex, 0, undefined);
    } else { //if first header then we need to make sure we don't delete the header with rows number
      this.displayedColumns.splice(cindex + 1, 0, undefined);
    }

    // adjust header.
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.displayedColumns.length - 1; i++ ) {
      this.displayedColumns[i + 1] = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    }

    // insert rows for new header
    let tempColArray = new Array();
    let dataSourceTemp = new Array();
    for (let r = 0; r < this.dataSource.data.length; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < this.displayedColumns.length - 1; c++) {
        if (cindex === c) { // if equal new header index then add new cell too
          tempColArray.push('        ');
          tempColArray.push(this.dataSource.data[r][c]);
        } else {
          tempColArray.push(this.dataSource.data[r][c]);
        }
      }
      dataSourceTemp.push(tempColArray);
      tempColArray = new Array();
    }
    this.dataSource.data = dataSourceTemp;
  }

  deleteRow(rIndex) {
    //prevent user from deleting all rows
    if ( this.dataSource.data.length === 1 ) {
      this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR'));
      this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.CANNOT_DELETE_ALL_ROWS'));
      return;
    }

    const tempDataSource = new Array()
    // insert empty cells for new row
    // look for the right row to edit
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.data.length; i++) {
      if (rIndex !== i) { // when not the index if deleted row then copy
        tempDataSource.push(this.dataSource.data[i]);
      }
    }
    this.dataSource.data = tempDataSource;
  }

  addRow(rIndex) {

    const newArr = new Array(this.displayedColumns.length);

    let tempDataSource = new Array()

    // insert empty cells for new row
    // look for the right row to edit
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.data.length; i++) {
      if (rIndex === i) { // if row index equal the index of clicked add button then add new header
        tempDataSource.push(this.dataSource.data[i]);
        tempDataSource.push(newArr);
      } else {
        tempDataSource.push(this.dataSource.data[i]);
      }
    }
    this.dataSource.data = tempDataSource;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TimesheetRoutingModule } from './timesheet-routing.module';
import { TimesheetComponent } from './timesheet.component';

import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/modules/shared.module';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [TimesheetComponent],
  imports: [
    TimesheetRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [TimesheetComponent]
})
export class TimesheetModule { }
```

However, I get this error, and I don't know how to solve it:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0302: The pipe 'slice' could not be found!
Error: NG0302: The pipe 'slice' could not be found!
    at getPipeDef$1 (core.js:25419)
    at Module.ɵɵpipe (core.js:25376)
    at TimesheetComponent_Template (timesheet.component.html:45)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11124)
    at renderView (core.js:10931)
    at renderComponent (core.js:12193)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:10796)
    at renderView (core.js:10956)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:24753)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:22792)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28193)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: import angular `CommonModule` to your TimesheetModule

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I've already tried, but it gives the same error...

Comment: angular root module should import `BrowserModule`which includes CommonModule. try importing it instead

Comment: If I try to add it, I get this new error: "BrowserModule has already been loaded"...